# How to fade in and expand a Modal from top right corner in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to get my CalendarFlyoutView to Fade in and expand from the top right corner in Xcode and Objective-C. This is the method existing in the implementation file:

```
- (void)presentInView:(UIView *)holderView completion:(void (^) (void))completion
{
    // make this view stretch
    CGRect upperRightR = CGRectMake (CGRectRight (holderView.bounds), 0, 1, 1);
    [self setFrame:upperRightR];
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.alpha = 0.0;

    [holderView addSubview:self];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimation_ExpandCalendarDuration
        animations:^{
          [self setFrame:holderView.bounds];
          self.alpha = 1.0;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
        }];
}
```

How do you get this to fade in and expand from the top right corner? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems correct, maybe check the auto-layout for the top right corner? This could cause the issue...